# R: Compare character strings across multiple columns to character string in a single column by row

Tags: r, data.table, string-matching

I am trying to create a variable that is a logical value when comparing one character string to more than two other character strings in a data.table and I need to ignore NA's.

Sample data for D2:

```
structure(list(ID = c("a001", "a002", "a003"), var1 = c("char1", 
"char1", "char2"), var2 = c("char1", NA, "char2"), var3 = c("char1", 
"char1", "char1")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000015eb1261ef0>)
```

Attempted a proposed solution below:

```
D2[, Match := apply(sapply(.SD, `==`, D2[, "var1"]), 1, any), .SDcols = 
c("var2", "var3")]
```

Result for a003 is TRUE whereas it should be FALSE because var1 and var3 don't match:

```
structure(list(ID = c("a001", "a002", "a003"), var1 = c("char1", 
"char1", "char2"), var2 = c("char1", NA, "char2"), var3 = c("char1", 
"char1", "char1"), Match = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 
0x0000015eb1261ef0>)
```

Desired Result:

```
structure(list(ID = c("a001", "a002", "a003"), var1 = c("char1", 
"char1", "char2"), var2 = c("char1", NA, "char2"), var3 = c("char1", 
"char1", "char1"), Match = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 
0x0000015eb1261ef0>)
```

Comment: Your desired result is identical to your sample data. Did you forget to include the proper expected output?

Comment: @Maurits Evers Never fails. I just edited the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Do you only want to compare `var1` with `var2`? What about `var3`? I'm still trying to understand the rules/logic behind your expected output. For row 3, is `Match = FALSE` because `var1 != var2`? Why is `Match = TRUE` for row 2?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yes exactly, I have more than two columns that I need to match with var1. I can not find one example of using mapply with more than two variables. ID a003 is not a match because var1 does not match one of either var2 or var3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the following

```
setDT(D1)
D1[, Match := apply(sapply(.SD, `==`, D1[, "var1"]), 1, any), .SDcols = c("var2", "var3")]
D1
#ID  var1  var2  var3 Match
#1: a001 char1 char1 char1  TRUE
#2: a002 char1  <NA> char1  TRUE
#3: a003 char2 char1 char1 FALSE
```

Explanation: We compare entries in the sub-`data.table` defined through `.SDcols` with entries in `D1[, "var1"]`; if there is `any` match, return `TRUE`, else `FALSE`.

---

### Update

In response to your comment, you can do

```
setDT(D1)
D1[, Match := apply(sapply(.SD, `==`, D1[, "var1"]), 1, all, na.rm = T), .SDcols = c("var2", "var3")]
```

Comment: If I change the value of var2 for ID a003 from char1 to char2 the result is TRUE whereas it should be FALSE because var3 is not a match with var1 even though var2 is.

Comment: @user3594490 That was not clear to me; I thought you wanted to have `TRUE` if at least one entry matched. I've made an edit, please take a look.

Comment: Yes! This works and my initial explanation needed to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

```
D2[, m := Reduce(`&`, data.table(
        sweep(as.matrix(.SD[, -"var1"]), 1L, .SD[["var1"]], function(x, y) is.na(x) | x==y))), 
    .SDcols=var1:var3]
```

Or using `melt`:

```
D2[, m := melt(D2, id.vars=c("ID", "var1"))[, any(var1==value, na.rm=TRUE), ID]$V1]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
D2 <- structure(list(ID = c("a001", "a002", "a003"), var1 = c("char1", 
    "char1", "char2"), var2 = c("char1", NA, "char2"), var3 = c("char1", 
        "char1", "char1")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
            "data.frame"))
setDT(D2)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with only `apply` by checking if the first value in the row is same as all the other elements in the row.

```
D2$match <- apply(D2[, -1], 1, function(x) all(x[1] == na.omit(x)))
D2
#     ID  var1  var2  var3 match
#1: a001 char1 char1 char1  TRUE
#2: a002 char1  <NA> char1  TRUE
#3: a003 char2 char2 char1 FALSE
```

Comment: could you please explain this logic

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as defaulting NA values:

```
else.na <- function(x, y) ifelse(is.na(x), y, x)
dt[,Match:= mapply('%in%', var1, else.na(var2, var1)) ,by = ID]
```

Comment: This works for var1 and var2 and produces desired output given my example. How can I apply it to var3 also? For example,only if the value for var1 matches the values for var2 and var3 would the result be TRUE.